# How to gather onMouse and onTouch so that the canvas can be use on mouse and ipad?

Tags: javascript, canvas, touch-event, onmousemove

i had a problem on confusing how to put ontouch inside my coding because i want it function on ipad, below is my code

```
    <script language="javascript">
function sig1()
{
    if(sig == null)
    {
        xclear('myCanvas');
    }
}
```

code for clear the line in canvas

```
<body id="main_body" class="no_guidelines" onload="sig1()" onmouseup="bodyonmouseup">
```

to let the canvas had fillstyle color and function

```
<canvas border=1 id="myCanvas" height=200 width=400 onmousedown="onmousedown()" onmouseup="onmouseup()" onmousemove="onmousemove()">Your browser does not support the application</canvas>
```

canvas that can draw line like signature

```
var sig = null;
      var ele;
      function bodyonmouseup(e)
{
    var ele;
    ele = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    ele.isDown = false;
}
function onmousedown(e)
{
    var ele,p;
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    ele = (e.srcElement);
    if (! ele) ele = e.target;
    ele.isDown = true; 
    ele.context = ele.getContext("2d");
    ele.context.lineWidth = 1;
    ele.context.beginPath();   
    ele.context.moveTo(e.offsetX,e.offsetY);
    sig.line = new Array();

    p = new Object();
    p.x = e.offsetX;
    p.y = e.offsetY;

    sig.p = p;
    sig.line[sig.line.length] = p;
    sig.lines[sig.lines.length] = sig.line;
}
function onmousemove(e)
{
    var ele,dx,dy,p;
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    ele = (e.srcElement);
    if (! ele) ele = e.target;
    if (! ele.isDown) return;
    ele.context.lineTo(e.offsetX,e.offsetY);
    ele.context.stroke();
    dx = e.offsetX - sig.p.x;
    dy = e.offsetY - sig.p.y;
    if (dx == 0 && dy == 0) return;
    sig.p = new Object();
    sig.p.x = e.offsetX;
    sig.p.y = e.offsetY;
    sig.line[sig.line.length] = sig.p;
}
```

So i want to know if i want keep both onMouse and ontouch, how i put the ontouch so that the canvas can be draw on ipad?? please help, it is urgent

Comment: here my html signature(http://jsfiddle.net/mvQRm/1/), have a look and hope you all can give me a help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this js. Your finger will be your mouse. They are converting all touch events to mouse events.

[jquery-ui-touch-punch](https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch)

Comment: thanks man, but i still can draw it on ipad or android phone after i input those javascript

Comment: can you give me a example by using the code i gave? because it not function on me...thanks again

Comment: add <script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script> this line. it will work. I think you need to put your codes on http://jsfiddle.net/ . People can help you, easily..

Comment: i think the touch-punch is just using jqery ui, but i just want it function in canvas.

Comment: Maybe. Put your codes to jsfiddle. Stackoverflow people like solving javascript problems on there. they will be interested in this question.

Comment: ya..i put on the jsfiddle already, hope got people help me T.T...just want to play this on touch devices...

Comment: Its done. http://jsfiddle.net/mvQRm/16/ .Ipad works great but, Pc version has problems in this way. Good luck.

Comment: wow, its works in touch devices!! thanks alot man!! but wonder why the pc version had minor problem..anyway.thanks!

Comment: hey, @Muhammet Göktürk Ayan, i found something weird when i trying to create again the canvas with touch version, it cant generate my drawing and stated undefined, and also just can draw straight line..hope you can help me... http://jsfiddle.net/Frebu/1/

Comment: Because on your onMouseMove(e) function, you are returning "if (! ele.isDown) return;"
I deleted this, ipad works fine. But pc has troubles.

Comment: I think you must look users device and if uses ipad, dont show this sentence. if uses pc, show it. It will work.,